# How can I get rid of this one pixel space between table cells?

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

I'm designing an email campaign and my requirements dictate no CSS. Don't get me started on that.

Everything's working fine except for the table noted below. The corner pieces are offset from the rest of the table by one pixel, and I cannot for the life of me figure out where I've got a misplaced semicolon or something.

The corner pieces are the same 15x15 image, just rotated 90 degrees depending on the corner. But you can see that the lines go right up to the edge, so there's no extra padding on the image.

[image: A corner, zoomed to like 3200%]

I've tried various iterations with less and more `<t*` attributes, setting things at the table, row and cell levels, and 99% of the online searches are leading me to Q&As about making sure that the spans are working properly--and I think mine are. The cap is still there when I use a border=1 attribute leading me to not suspect borders as the culprit.

I'm using 4 columns x 3 rows, with the outermost columns and rows housing a 15px X 15px corner image (gif), and the cells between the corners have a white background with a 1px X 1px gif spacer aligned and stretched to give me a line between the corner images.

The center section is a cell with an icon, followed by a cell of text. I need to create 5 of these bullet-point things; I added a second, blank box to show what happens when two of these butt up against each other.

Anyone have any ideas for what I can look at, what I need to add or what I need to subtract from my code?

[image]

```
<html>
 <body style='background:f3f7f8'>
     <table border=0 width=430 style='font-size=12px;cellpadding=0;cellspacing=0;border-collapse:collapse;'>
       <tr>
        <td width=15 height=15><img src="644810_tl.png" width=15 height=15 ></td>
        <td colspan=2 valign="top" style='background:ffffff'><img src="dkgray.gif" width=400 height=2></td>
        <td width=15 height=15><img src="644810_tr.png" width=15 height=15></td>  
       </tr>

       <tr>
        <td style='background=ffffff' align=left><img src="dkgray.gif" width=2 height=100></td>
        <td style='background=ffffff' width=75 align=center valign=center><img src="icon-pdf.gif"></td>
        <td style='background=ffffff' width=325 align=left valign=cener><strong>Lorem Ipsum<br></strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dignissim risus at quam hendrerit aliquet. Nunc et felis elit. Fusce pharetra adipiscing velit vel pharetra. Donec ornare velit sed massa tempor at tempor sem lacinia. Quisque enim nisl, auctor sit amet volutpat eget, porttitor sit amet tortor. Nulla ut sodales magna. Morbi adipiscing est urna, ac gravida erat.</td>
        <td style='background=ffffff' align=right><img src="dkgray.gif" width=2 height=100></td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
        <td width=15 height=15 style='background=ffffff'><img src="644810_bl.png" width=15 height=15></td>
        <td colspan=2 valign="bottom" style='background:ffffff;cellpadding=0;cellspacing=0;border-collapse:collapse'><img src="dkgray.gif" width=400 height=2></td>
        <td width=15 height=15 style='background=ffffff'><img src="644810_br.png" width=15 height=15></td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
        <td width=15 height=15><img src="644810_tl.png" width=15 height=15 ></td>
        <td colspan=2 valign="top" style='background:ffffff'><img src="dkgray.gif" width=400 height=2></td>
        <td width=15 height=15><img src="644810_tr.png" width=15 height=15></td>  
       </tr>

       <tr>
        <td width=15 height=15 style='background=ffffff'><img src="644810_bl.png" width=15 height=15></td>
        <td colspan=2 valign="bottom" style='background:ffffff;cellpadding=0;cellspacing=0;border-collapse:collapse'><img src="dkgray.gif" width=400 height=2></td>
        <td width=15 height=15 style='background=ffffff'><img src="644810_br.png" width=15 height=15></td>
       </tr>
     </table>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're specifying `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` as though they were CSS properties. They're not - they're attributes that must live on the `table` tag.

Also, HEX colour references should have the `#` before them.

Comment: Yep...first line of my post: I'm designing an e-mail campaign. I am so not used to working with my CSS tied behind my back. :) So the `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` at the `<table` level is correct syntactically? or does it need to be a standalone attribute outside of `style=' '`?Thanks for the catch on the # for hex codes. I had to do a global replace on the colors a couple hours ago...must've killed it then by mistake.

Comment: Sorry, I really should read more closely. Yes - `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` are HTML attributes - they are not CSS properties. As such, they need to be declared, with values, in the table's opening tag.

Comment: Fantastico! It works, I accepted your answer, and posted a summary of my solution as another answer for future generations.

Comment: Great - but please don't post your response as an answer. Answers are for, of course, answers :) Feel free to modify your original question instead, to show the eventual solution.

Answer (score 9):

Use border collapse, this will collapse borders of cells to one border.

```
table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Comment: I've already got the border-collapse:collapse attribute set as part of the style attribute in my <td> tags...is there a different way I should be using this? Is there another proper syntax of which I'm unaware?

Comment: you should be applying it to the table not to the td cells

Comment: Very true, I had not noticed that, are you sure your images don't have extra padding on them?

Comment: @JonTaylor I double checked my images, they're exactly 15x15, and the lines run to the edge. I'll post one...

Comment: Id suggest fixing the things @Utkanos suggested, the css ones shouldn't affect it but they shouldn't be there, not as css anyway.

Comment: try setting cell spacing and cell padding as attributes of the table rather than css, as they should be, and see what happens.

Comment: @Sam ah ok, any particular reason why?

Comment: @JonTaylor Outlook 2007 + 10 use the word rendering engine to show html emails

Comment: @Ah ok, did not know this.  Useful to know though.

Comment: Thanks Jon... this did the trick border-collapse:collapse; on everything ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the additional line height from your CSS. Worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).